# leanModal.js - Simplest jQuery Modal Script Troubleshooting

Tags: jquery, css, modal-dialog

Man oh man. After slaving over leanModal, the simplest possible Modal Window script, for many hours, I still can't get it to trigger.

leanModal: http://leanmodal.finelysliced.com.au

My site: http://wlvrtn.com/sites/nms-leanmodal/

Help a jQuery noob out?

---

HEAD:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_/js/jquery.leanModal.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('a[rel*=leanModal]').leanModal({ top : 200, closeButton: ".modal_close" });       
        });
</script>
```

CSS:

```
#lean_overlay {
position: fixed;
z-index: 10000;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
height:100%;
width:100%;
background: #000;
display: none;
}

#test {
width: 600px;
display:none;
background: #FFF;   
}
```

HTML:

```
<a class="request-consultation" rel="leanModal" name="test" href="#test">
    Request Complimentary Consultation
</a>                 

<div id="test">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Aha! Removing the following code from the footer (which had been placed in the first place by html5reset.org): <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='_/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'>\x3C/script>")</script>

Comment: I'll assume jQuery should only be referenced once. So, where is the proper place to reference the latest jQuery? <head>, or just before </body>?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is totally work, please check the your `jquery.leanModal.min.js` path is right or not. `_/` or should be `./`

Take a look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gAVuA/).

Comment: http://wlvrtn.com/sites/nms-leanmodal/_/js/jquery.leanModal.min.js is indeed the path to the script.

Comment: Does it matter that the HEAD is contained in a PHP include located here? http://wlvrtn.com/sites/nms-leanmodal/_/includes/head.php

Comment: this is hard to know. try one thing, set relative path start from root. in this case: /sites/nms-leanmodal/_/js/jquery.leanModal.min.js

Answer (score 1):

try adding the third parameter.

```
$('#foo').leanModal({top:100,overlay:0.5,closeButton:".modal_close"});
```

Answer (score -1):

You should also add the Jquery Library.